# Using python to check existing accounts in several services

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib, hotmail

I'm trying to use urllib and urlib2 to check if a public user profile exists in various socialnets.
Now i'm stuck trying to checking www.live.com. 
If i visit for example this url `http://spaces.live.com/profile.aspx?mem=Example@hotmail.com`, and the email of mem param exists, it redirects to the profile of this account, like this `http://profile.live.com/cid-f5ee5e2a441e7771/` even if the profile is not public. Otherwise the account does not exist.

How should i use URLError (or else) to detect the redirect? Is there any better way to do it?

EDIT:

Self Solved!!!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import urllib2 
from urllib2 import HTTPError, URLError
nick=str(sys.argv[1])
pref_live="http://spaces.live.com/profile.aspx?mem="
suf_live_01="@hotmail.com"
try:  
    f = urllib2.urlopen( pref_live + nick + suf_live_01 )
    print f.read()  
    f.close()  
except HTTPError, e:  
    print "error"  
    print e.code  
except URLError, e:  
    print "error"  
    print e.reason
```

If error is 404, account exists, else (500), it does not exists

EDIT 2:

here is the final code, thank you guys for your help :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import urllib2 
from urllib2 import HTTPError, URLError
prefix_live="http://spaces.live.com/profile.aspx?mem="
sufix_live=["@hotmail.com","@live.com"]
try:
    nick=str(sys.argv[1])
except:
    print "Username needed"
    print "Usage:"
    print sys.argv[0], "[username]"
    nick=''

def checking():
    for domain in sufix_live:
        try:  
            f = urllib2.urlopen( prefix_live + nick + domain )
            print f.read()    
            f.close()    
        except HTTPError, e:  
            if e.code == 404:
                print 'Yeah! %s%s exists' % (nick, domain) 
            elif e.code == 500:
                print 'Doh! %s%s Does NOT exists'% (nick, domain)
            else:
                print 'other error'
                print e.code
        except URLError, e:     
            print "There was an error"  
            print e.reason    

if nick != '':
    checking()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a comment asking for clarification and a code sample, but alas I can't add comments yet. However I'll take a wild stab in the dark at answering your question.

If we assume you are doing something like this:

```
request = urllib2.Request('http://someurl.com')
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
if response.geturl() != 'http://someurl.com':
    print "redirected"
else:
    print "not redirected"
```

then in the first instance if urllib2 gets a redirect code (e.g. response 300) it will handle the redirection for you and fetch the URL that the server redirects to.

You can then establish whether in fact you were redirected by checking the value of response.geturl()

Comment: Thanks! your code is quite simpler, although mine is useful to handle several error codes.
Anyway thanks so much for your sugestion, it will be useful for me soon.

Answer (score 0):

consider using the [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) module.

It exports the interface of urllib2, and also includes a lot of handy stuff for navigating web sites (content parsing, forms, redirects, cookies, etc).

Comment: Thanks! although i have solved it, i`ll take a look closer to mechanize, it looks simplier.